# ES6 `fetch is undefined`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm building a site with ES6 and Babel.

In a script file, I need to make an ajax call to a service on server. For that I'm doing like this:

```
fetch('url').then(
    response => response.json()
).then(
    supervisoryItems => doSomething(supervisoryItems)
)
```

In Google Chrome this works just fine, but it does not work on Firefox or IE (I'm getting the error `fetch is undefined`).
Searching on Google I found this should fix it:

```
import promise from 'es6-promise'
promise.polyfill()
```

Sadly it does not change anything, I have the same issue. Any help?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You need to add the 'isomorphic-fetch' module to your 'package.json' and then import this.

```
npm install --save isomorphic-fetch es6-promise
```

Then in your code

```
import "isomorphic-fetch"
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch

Comment: There's a couple other implementations too, but I hear this one's good.

Comment: BTW, the `import` statement is case-sensitive. (Cannot edit one char.)

Comment: By running to above command, other packages (Express Module for ex.) were removed

Comment: I invested great deal of efforts while developing in this new technologes (react, es6, node). When all looked good and I gave my PO a link to the site, great was my disappointment when it didn't work in Internet Exlorer.   Console errors were not very descriptive.  The solution was: 1. import 'babel-polyfill' in entry point script (App.tsx) 2. import 'isomorphic-fetch' in script doing the fetching

Comment: If you're using Angular, you run `npm install --save isomorphic-fetch es6-promise` and just paste
`import "isomorphic-fetch"`
inside your `polyfills.ts` file

Answer (score 20):

I will use the two following cdn like this:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.5.0/bluebird.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.js"></script>
```

Comment: This worked really well for me as I was using React as a lib in a .net project and didnt want to faff with npm installs etc. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Babel-polyfill (http://babeljs.io/#polyfill) currently doesn't include fetch in the polyfill. I was thinking of adding it though.

But yeah can use https://github.com/github/fetch

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Webpack's [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) with the [imports-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imports-loader) and [exports-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exports-loader) packages as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44908274/3358139), which removes the need to import anything in your code:

```js
config.plugins = [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'fetch': 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
    })
];
```

At the time of writing there's a compatibility issue with the 3.0.0 version of `whatwg-fetch`. The workaround is using the following:

```js
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    fetch: 'exports-loader?self.fetch!whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd'
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use `isomorphic-unfetch` instead of `isomorphic-fetch`, because it is able to work like a [ponyfill](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ponyfill) and not a polyfill.

The difference is that it doesn't affect the rest of code and it is more transparent of the dependencies you have.

---

Install:

```sh
yarn add isomorphic-unfetch
```

Usage:

```js
// using ES6 modules
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

// using CommonJS modules
var fetch = require('isomorphic-unfetch');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just went through this last night. In the end, after trying all sorts of things, the solution was fairly simple:

```
fetch('url').then(
response => response.json()
).then(
supervisoryItem => doSomething(supervisoryItem)
)
```

became

```
window.fetch('url').then(
response => response.json()
).then(
supervisoryItem => doSomething(supervisoryItem)
)
```

TL;DR fetch(stuff) should be **window**.fetch(stuff)
**EDIT** This worked for me on Chrome

Comment: Depends. If browser doesn't implement it natively you still need to add an implementation.

Comment: Chrome, yes.  IE, no.

Answer (score 1):

There is browser support for every new functionality added in Javascript. 
You can see browser support on https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch

Follow the following 2 steps to use fetch on IE11

**Step 1: Install 3 packages**

`npm i whatwg-fetch @babel/polyfill es6-promise --save`

@babel/polyfill - to use polyfill in babel

whatwg-fetch - includes fetch functionality

es6-promise - fetch polyfill includes promise which is also not supported by IE11

**Step 2: Add Entry Point in webpack.config**

**entry: [ "whatwg-fetch", "@babel/polyfill", "./src/js/index.js"]**

```
require("es6-promise").polyfill();

const config = {
  entry: [ "whatwg-fetch", "@babel/polyfill", "./src/js/index.js"],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules : [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: You can find problem by watching this video : https://youtu.be/4qek1pbjNeY

Answer (score -4):

Window.fetch or fetch is the same... technically fetch() is a global method of the Window object