# fetch method is not defined using ES6 fetch in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have a trouble with fetch functions in my first react js app.

This is the structure of my project:

```
hello-world
  -- app
     -- components
       -- main.jsx
  -- node_modules
  -- public
     -- build.js
     -- index.html
  -- package.json
```

This is what I've installed using npm:

```
npm install react react-dom babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-es2015    babel-preset-react webpack --save-dev
npm install --save isomorphic-fetch es6-promise
```

I use webpack
webpack.config

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/components/main.jsx',
  output: {
    path: './public/',
    filename: "build.js",
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -w"
  },
  "author": "mannuk",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "react": "^0.14.8",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.8",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "^3.3.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

This is the file where I build the UI:

main.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import 'es6-promise';

class Person extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {people : []};
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    fetch('xxx/people',
      method: 'get',
      headers: {'token' : 'xxx'}
      )
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((people) => {
        this.setState({ people: people })
      })
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.people[0].name}></input>
      </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Person/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

If I try to run it through the browser it fails (fetch method is not defined) I have also checked this releated post [ES6 `fetch is undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484156/es6-fetch-is-undefined) and I have included the import with no success. I also included es6-promise import but it fails too.

What am I doing wrong? Is it a config problem or what? When I run 'npm run build' there is no error and the build.js seems to be ok.

Comment: why don't you import fetch with `import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';` instead of `import 'isomorphic-fetch';`?

Comment: As a side note, you seem to be missing the curly braces for the object literal that you're passing as a second argument to the `fetch()` call. It should be `fetch('xxx/people', { method: 'get', headers: {'token' : 'xxx'} });`

Comment: Not sure you want to exclude all node_modules in the line ; exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,

Comment: @saadq you are right. Idk why when I run npm run build does not fail if I have missing curly braces...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's an exported default, so...

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding a polyfill for this is the correct approach. Looking at one of my latest projects you just need to do the following imports;

```
import promise from 'es6-promise';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

promise.polyfill();
```

It looks like you've not quite got the es6-promise import correct which requires the .polyfill() method be called. I'd recommend putting these in the entry point of the application as you should only need to import them once.

I'd also recommend you include the babel polyfill;

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
```

Comment: Can you explain me what a polyfill is?

Comment: A polyfill, or polyfiller, is a piece of code (or plugin) that provides the technology that you, the developer, expect the browser to provide natively. This is well covered by remysharp https://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill

Comment: thanks. So if I import es6-promise I need to call promise.polyfill before class Person...? The solution that @D. Walsh provided it works and it only requires to import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'. I mention that because I saw the .polyfill() in some tutorials but idk why they were using it.