# Module not found when using import instead of require

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am trying to use `import` instead of `require` for all modules in my project, but some older npm modules only have instructions for `require`.

In the case of 'isomorphic-fetch' I can't find the proper way to use import:

works

```
require('isomorphic-fetch')
```

fails

```
import 'isomporphic-fetch'   
import Something from 'isomorphic-fetch'

// error Can't resolve 'isomporphic-fetch' from Project/src/js/
```

Converting to `import` does work with the `es6-promise` module.

works

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill()
```

works

```
import Something from 'es6-promise'
Something.polyfill()
```

Comment: What's doing the loading here? Node `--experimental-modules`, Webpack, etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fetch method is not defined using ES6 fetch in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707954/fetch-method-is-not-defined-using-es6-fetch-in-react)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `import` does work with other modules, and `require('isomorphic-fetch')` works, it's probably a [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) problem.

Try `import * as Something from 'isomorphic-fetch'`

If that works, it's because `isomorphic-fetch` does not do `export deafult` so you have to pull in the `import`s by name, or use the notation I wrote above. Take a look at the MDN link I put on top.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Still not sure why I need `Something`, since that variable is never used. `import * from 'isomorphic-fetch'` doesn't work.

Comment: Looking at the [repo](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/blob/master/fetch-npm-node.js), it's only export is the `fetch` function. But in addition to exporting it, he overrides the `global` as well. So as he writes in the `README` you don't need to `import` at all, just `require` without assigning. I agree that `es6-promise`'s polyfill API is more easily understandable

Comment: Yes, I realise that just `require` also works, but I would prefer sticking to one syntax. It would be great if just `import 'isomporphic-fetch'` worked.