# Babel not Polyfilling Fetch when using babel-preset-env

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm using Webpack and Babel to build and transpile my ES6 code. However I am missing important Polyfills when trying to support older browsers. e.g iOS8.

Here's my Webpack.config

```
const versions = {
  v1: './src/js/v1.js',
  v2: './src/js/v2.js',
  v3: './src/js/v3.js',
};

module.exports = {
  entry: versions,
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: '[name].min.js'
  },
  externals: {
    'jquery': 'jQuery'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.js$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      }, {
        test: /\.hbs$/,
        loader: 'handlebars-loader',
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 3 versions", "iOS >= 8"]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Firstly, why isn't this Polyfill being added? And secondly how do I add it? I attempted adding this to my `.babelrc` `"plugins": ["whatwg-fetch"]` with no luck.

I believe I can add it to the entry of my Webpack config, but that won't work in my instance as I have multiple scripts I am trying to build separately.

Thanks in advance for any help. My diminishing head of hair is especially thankful!

Comment: Very good question. I also ended up importing the `whatwg-fetch` module to solve the issue, but having that polyfill as part of Babel would be more convenient.

Answer (score 11):

You can add the resolution of `fetch` inside your `webpack.config.js` file.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  'fetch': 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
})
```

Inside your `plugins` section.
After that, inside your code, just use `fetch`. You won't need to import it whatsoever. Of course, you need `imports-loader` and `exports-loader`.

Comment: Thanks. After installing these libraries and adding your suggested code, I'm getting `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'imports-loader' in '/Users/...`

Comment: As mentioned, you have to have those modules. Have you installed them? :) `npm i --save-dev imports-loader exports-loader`. Plus, is your webpack resolving the modules from `node_modules` folder??

Comment: Yep, installed them. And have just added `resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
  }` to my config, but still get same error :/

Comment: That's weird. I use this very configuration on my repo and it works like a charm. Did you remove the `plugins` option from `.babelrc`?

Comment: Not to worry @Ematipico, error on my part. That works great, thank you! I'm trying to do the same for Object.setPrototypeOf. Any ideas?

Comment: You should be loading `babel-polyfill`.

Comment: Yeah exactly :)

Comment: There's an issue with this as of `whatwg-fetch` 3.0.0. The workaround (as suggested in [this comment on their issue tracker](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/659#issuecomment-437936495)) is to replace the line suggested above with: `fetch: 'exports-loader?self.fetch!whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd'`

Comment: `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   fetch: 'exports-loader?self.fetch!whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd'
})`  under plugins of webpack.config.js  and `"es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.7.0"` in package.json under devDependencies

Comment: None of these solutions work for me anymore. I get a `ValidationError: Invalid options object. Exports Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.` error.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you're trying to add a polyfill for a web/DOM standard, not a JS polyfill. Babel only handles transpiling and polyfilling the standard ECMAScript language features, it does not handle web/browser specifications, like `fetch`. So you shouldn't load it with the babel loader in Webpack.

I've tried the other solutions offered here myself, but none of them works anymore. What worked for me was simply installing the package `npm i whatwg-fetch --save-dev` then adding it in the `entry` configuration option field, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["whatwg-fetch", "./src/yourapp.js"]
}
```

Where `./src/yourapp.js` should be the entry point of your app.
I'm posting this in case someone will run into the same issue and the other solutions won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Babel doesn't add polyfill for web specifications. You can only use polyfills to implement ECMAScript's proposals listed [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposals). It needs to be implemented manually. [Github's fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) or other alternatives can be used.

Answer (score 1):

In my case Error was ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

I had the error on firebase with global this and server rendering, following some solutions, I ended up with adding a plugin in webpack
then rebuilding I ended with a bunch of errors in the type of "multi ..." which are basically that there are multiple definitions of that library

```
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           Promise: 'es6-promise',
           fetch: 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?exports!global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',}),
```

AND FINALLY IN RESOLVE section

```
mainFields: ['main']
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer! This worked for me! I was using firebase with electron-react app. I had the 'fetch not defined in main process' error. I have to remove the 'Promise: 'es6-promise' ' part in your answer to make it work. And the 'mainFields:['main'] ' need to be added to 'resolve' section of webpack config. Hope this answer will help others.

Comment: I am having a similiar problem using rollup.js. Could explain what this main field is and why it works to solve the fetch error