# In Pycharm, I can't fetch a JSON file and cannot install fetch

Tags: javascript, django, pycharm, fetch

I am working on a Django project in Pycharm. I need to fetch API in the Javascript file, but it gives me an internal server error and error in the console showing the fetch line. It seems like it is not recognizing fetch at all.

This is an example of how I use fetch in my code;

```
    document.querySelector('#compose-form').onsubmit = function () {
     fetch('/emails', {
              method: 'POST',
              body: JSON.stringify({
                  recipients: in_recipients,
                  subject: in_subject,
                  body: in_body,
              })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
                if (result.message !== "Email sent successfully."){
                  alert(result.error)
                }
            });
        };
```

My code is actually working on Vscode but can't make it work in Pycharm. I tried

```
     pip install fetch
```

I got the following error;

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\bilge\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n1v3op9a\fetch\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    description = file(os.path.join(here, 'README.txt')).read()
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full 
 command output.
```

Also tried

```
        python setup.py egg_info
```

says:

```
        can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such a thing like

```
           pip install fetch
```

You need to change in the settings, Languages and Frameworks, and find Javascript libraries. Add the TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

fetch needs to be polyfilled because,  when you compile code you’re not adding any new global or primitive properties that you may need. fetch would be a new property on the global namespace, therefore, it needs to be polyfilled.

So they cannot be compiled with babel. See further details here [Babel not Polyfilling Fetch when using babel-preset-env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908044/babel-not-polyfilling-fetch-when-using-babel-preset-env)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know @bdemirka if your issue was solved because I just encountered the problem with Pycharm, I am learning JavaScript. Everything was working fine then all-over sudden

[image]

pycharm seems not to recognize JavaScripts's `document.querySelector()`

What I have tried so far:

- Restored pycharm to default
- Reinstalled node
- Change setting as suggested by @mr_nocoding(settings, Languages and Frameworks, and find Javascript libraries. Add the TypeScript.)

  `fetch()` is being detected fine by Pycharm. Any ideas?