# next js react app fetch not defined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to clone the following next.js react app and run it on localhost:3000

https://github.com/elee-ittdublin/lab6-nextjs

when I open localhost:3000 I get the following error

Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): fetch is not defined
Function._callee$
./pages/index.js:22

```
20 | // see https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages
>22 | Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
24 |   const url = 'https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=batman';
```

I have tried to research what I am doing wrong but I still can not fix my problem. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Cheers

Comment: what about that answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484156/es6-fetch-is-undefined

Comment: thanks for the reply buddy. errors are gone although when i click on the batman links i get '404 This page could not be found.' so the fetch is not working, any idea why?

Comment: Fetch is working. The issue you have, when you click on the batman links you are redirected to a page on your app that doesn't exist. That line is wrong 
```<Link as={`/p/${show.id}`} href={`/post?id=${show.id}`}>```

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the examples here [examples](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples) and search for `fetch`, you will see what they are using. In the examples is `node-fetch` - [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` is a **predefined** method in the **browser** but your function works in server side, so it does not work.

There is an npm package that basically combines browser's fetch and node-fetch together, it is named isomorphic-unfetch, you can install it via the command `npm install isomorphic-unfetch`.

After that use `unfetch` method anywhere u want to use `fetch` method.

**PS:**
In the newer versions of Next.JS ( 10.0.0 and above ) you should not see this problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be the package is not installed. Try installing  https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-unfetch

Comment: thanks for the reply; i tried installing the package. i'm still getting the same errors

Comment: ... and this is more like a comment than an answer (especially since it does not seem to address OP's issue).