# how to fix 'fetch' is undefined in ie11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am coming to an issue where my code below, says that `'fetch' is undefined` in internet explorer 11. I am using the latest jquery which is `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` and I even tried `$.ajax` instead of `fetch` but that did not work. Can anyone help me solve this issue, with my code below. That it can even work in ie11. thank you very much!

when I do `$_ajax` instead `fetch` I get an console error saying `res.text is not a function TypeError: res.text is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
"use strict";

$(function () {
    var myData = [];


    $.get("#{request.contextPath}/JobSearchItem.xhtml", function (data) {

        $("#searchTextField").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: myData,
            select: function select(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var url = '#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml';
                var searchValue = ui.item.value;
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append('searchValue', searchValue);
                fetch(url, {
                    body: data,
                    method: "post"
                }).then(function (res) {
                    return res.text();
                }).then(function (text) {
                    $('#results').append($(text).find('#textTable'));
                    $('#results').append($(text).find('table'));
                    $('#results').append($(text).find('#bestTable'));
                    $("#clearone").show();
                });
            },
            response: function response(event, ui) {
                if (!ui.content.length) {
                    var message = { value: "", label: "NO SEARCH RESULT FOUND" };
                    ui.content.push(message);
                }
            }

        });


        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
            myData.push({
                id: v.id,
                label: v.label,
                value: v.id

            });
        });
    });


    $("#sJobClass").change(function () {
        var jobClassCd = $(this).val();
        if (jobClassCd !== 0) {
            var url = '#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml';
            var searchValue = $('#sJobClass').val();
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('searchValue', searchValue);
             fetch(url, {
                body: data,
                method: "post"
            }).then(function (res) {
                return res.text();
            }).then(function (text) {
                $('#results').append($(text).find('#textTable'));
                $('#results').append($(text).find('table'));
                $('#results').append($(text).find('#bestTable'));
                $("#clearone").show();
            });
        };
    });


});
```

Comment: Using `$.ajax()` or some other jQuery variation would be what I'd do and it does work from IE11. You said it "doesn't work" but you provided no details or the code for your attempt, so really it's hard to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 \`fetch is undefined\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484156/es6-fetch-is-undefined)

Comment: So, in `fetch(url, {
                    body: data,
                    method: "post"` ,  I did `$.ajax` instead of `fetch`

Comment: @Pointy see updated question at my attempt.

Comment: The `$.ajax()` jQuery API predates the `fetch()` API and is not (and was never intended to be) a drop-in replacement. It is however a way to set up and issue an HTTP request from your JavaScript code, which is I assume your basic goal.

Answer (score 0):

Do this-

```
npm install --save isomorphic-fetch es6-promise
```

import it in your code and use it.

Comment: @AshsayMandwarya .. so in the command prompt or in my project directory should I install ?

Comment: Install node in your system and then install the npm package in your project directory.

Comment: I did, and should I import like this `import "isomorphic-fetch" "use strict";` , correct?

Comment: "use strict";
import "isomorphic-fetch";

Comment: If this is the answer you are looking for mark it as correct so others can get help too.

Comment: But,  I get a console error at  `import "isomorphic-fetch"`  as `Unexpected string`

Comment: Try with this require('isomorphic-fetch');

Comment: @SuzyHakobyan: You don't seem to be using a module bundler, so using an npm module is not what you are looking for. Use jQuery's Ajax API and read its documentation to use it correctly.

Comment: So, this did not solve my question. I don't want to use any node packages. Can anyone help me solve this with my code above

Comment: Can you describe how to import and use it? Its a vague answer as it stands.

Comment: So, this did not solve my question. I don't want to use any node packages. Can anyone help me solve this with my code above

Comment: @FelixKling SO, instead of `fetch` use `$.post`?

Comment: @SuzyHakobyan: Yes. And read the documentation for how to use it correctly. (this is basically what Pointy  meant in his comment)

Comment: I tried doing `$.post(url, {
                body: data,
                method: "post"
            }).`  but it gave me an `Illegal invocation`.. if you can please show me a working code , so I can see what I missed. thanks

Comment: Please refer this link and go through it thoroughly    https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/